# Encapsulamento em Kotlin

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, kotlin, encapsulamento

Estou iniciando meus estudos em Kotlin e estou tentando resolver o seguinte problema:

Crie uma classe para representar uma pessoa, com os atributos privados de nome, data de
nascimento e altura. Crie os métodos públicos necessários para sets e gets e também um
método para imprimir todos dados de uma pessoa. Crie um método para calcular a idade
da pessoa.

Ao tornar privados os atributos, não consegui acessá-los mais. Como posso utilizar os "getters" e "setters" para acessar os atributos?

Meu código:

```
fun main() {
    val dadosJoao = Dados()
    dadosJoao.nome = "João"
    dadosJoao.altura = 1.83
    dadosJoao.nascimento = 1948
    println(dadosJoao.nascimento)
    println(dadosJoao.altura)
    println(dadosJoao.calculaIdade())

}

class Dados {
    var nome = ""
    var idade = 0
    var altura = 0.0
    var nascimento = 0

    fun calculaIdade(idade: Int)  {
        idade = 2021 - nascimento
        return this.idade
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tentar acessar esses atributos do seu objeto `dadosJoao` (na verdade o certo é chamá-los de campos) a partir de fora da classe como você fez, nessa função `main()` que não pertence à classe `Dados`, esses atributos não poderão ser acessados porque não estarão visíveis. Eles somente estão visíveis para código (funções) que estiver sendo declarado dentro da sua classe `Dados`, como foi o caso da sua última função `calculaIdade()`. É isso que significa eles serem privados.

Note que esta última função, se for pública, você consegue chamar de fora da classe a partir de um objeto dessa classe, por exemplo a partir do objeto `dadosJoao` fazendo `dadosJoao.calculaIdade()`, portanto se você programar essa função para retornar o valor de um campo privado, esse valor será acessível por quem chama essa função do lado de fora da classe e recebe seu retorno.

Se uma função pertence a uma classe (o que nos leva a chamar essa função de "método"), você só poderá chamá-la se tiver uma referência (variável) para um objeto que foi criado com base nessa classe, como é o caso da sua variável `dadosJoao`.

A intenção é não expor esses campos diretamente para o lado de fora da classe, e sim de maneira mais controlada através de métodos públicos, digamos, "porteiros".

Assim fica possível controlar via código que a data de nascimento de um objeto seja definida uma vez só e não seja alterada mais vezes, por exemplo. Se ela ficar pública isso não será possível pois a qualquer hora uma data de nascimento da pessoa à qual ela pertence poderá ser mudada, o que seria indesejável (aliás, note pelos dados em questão que você está modelando (projetando) uma classe `Pessoa`, esse nome de classe é mais apropriado no seu caso do que `Dados`. Isso porque essa classe Pessoa não terá somente dados, mas também comportamentos (funções/métodos que interagem com esses dados).

Se você declarar uma função pública ou pelo menos não-privada `getNome()` dentro da sua classe que retorne como resultado o valor de um campo `nome` que está privado na classe (por ter sido declarada dentro da classe essa função tem acesso aos campos dessa classe mesmo se eles forem privados, é uma questão de escopo e visibilidade), essa função será o que muitos chamam de *getter*. O campo `nome` continuará inacessível diretamente por quem de fora da classe chamar `meuObjeto.nome`, **mas será acessível de maneira indireta chamando em seu lugar** `meuObjeto.getNome()`. Só não sei exatamente como se faz isso na sintaxe do Kotlin.

Para entender melhor é preciso ter a noção do que são encapsulamento e *information hiding* (ocultação da informação) em orientação a objetos.

Primeiramente vamos lembrar que uma classe é uma "fôrma" que você programa com a intenção de definir o que os objetos a serem criados com base nessa classe irão ter em termos de estado (variáveis) e comportamento (lógica) durante a execução do código. Aí para cada objeto que for instanciado (criado) esse estado irá variar individualmente, tanto a partir de como foram inicializados como com base na interação entre os diferentes objetos de diferentes classes na sua aplicação. Grosso modo é isso, em orientação a objetos baseada em classes.

Basicamente, em objetos você deve ter o princípio de isolar o que está "do lado de dentro" do que está "do lado de fora" de um objeto construindo uma espécie de barreira lógica na classe que o define usando conceitos como modificadores de acesso (tornar privado, público, etc.) aplicados a campos (que é o nome que se dá a variáveis que foram programadas para pertencer ao objeto, em oposição a variáveis locais ou globais) e a métodos (que é o nome que se dá a essas "funções" programadas dentro de uma classe e que acabam pertencendo a essa classe, ou melhor, aos seus objetos), bem como praticando uma certa maneira de programar classes.

Isso permite a você isolar o que se encontra dentro do objeto (detalhes de implementação, estruturas de dados que não interessa para o lado de fora quais são, algoritmos específicos) do que é visto do lado de fora do objeto, que fica mais estável. Esta estabilidade é muito desejável. Torna-se possível fazer alterações e melhorias nas parte interna do objeto que não necessariamente irão impactar a interface pública (os métodos públicos) fornecidos pelo objeto, que são os "serviços" ou a utilidade de alto nível que esse objeto oferece para seus utilizadores. O objetivo é sempre tentar minimizar esse impacto e expor uma interface tão estável quanto possível.

*Getter* é o nome que se dá a um método público, ou pelo menos não-privado, que expõe (retorna) alguma informação de dentro do objeto. Como esse método pertence à classe que você está programando, ele tem acesso a campos privados dessa classe e pode inclusive retorná-los no retorno da função, efetivamente "publicando" esses campos para quem chama esse método a partir do lado de fora.

O pessoal costuma fazer a associação de que um getter chamado por exemplo `getNome()` deve sempre trazer a variável `nome` que é privada dentro do objeto, e para muitos um getter é só isso, mas isso não é necessariamente verdade, visto que um getter "pelado" invalida essa barreira lógica (o que em alguns casos, como objetos que simplesmente servem para transportar dados, não chega a ser problema, mas pode ser em objetos que fazem parte do chamado modelo de domínio, que implementam regras de negócio por exemplo).

Mesma coisa os *setters*, que são métodos públicos ou não-privados que alteram algo dentro do objeto e o pessoal vê muito como `setNome(novoNome)`, para alterar um campo privado `nome`, mas isso não deve ser necessariamente verdade.

O conceito de objeto significa colocar juntos algum estado e os comportamentos associados a esse estado, isso de colocar juntas essas duas coisas que estão relacionadas e dar um nome a elas é o que se chama de encapsulamento. Ocultação da informação é essa separação que eu descrevi entre a interface pública e os detalhes de implementação/estado interno, que decorrem de isolar esses dois lados logicamente (muitas gente confunde isso com encapsulamento).

No seu caso quando seus campos nome, etc. eram públicos, não estava ocorrendo a ocultação da informação. Quando ficaram privados esta passou a ocorrer. Se você criar getters e setters para eles ela poderá ou não deixar de ocorrer, principalmente se você não fizer validação de dados no setter, ou expuser campos que não deveriam ser modificados, como `data_de_nascimento`, fornecendo um setter para eles, ou ainda se expuser um estado interno mutável (como uma referência a um outro objeto guardado internamente) que fique sujeito a ser alterado diretamente pelo lado de fora, em vez de uma cópia imutável dessa informação. Já um `getIdade()` cujo retorno é calculado a partir da data de nascimento, preserva a ocultação da informação (você não está expondo a data de nascimento) e demonstra o conceito do encapsulamento.

O que vai ter numa interface pública depende dos serviços que são interessantes um objeto fornecer. Uma classe `Pedido` por exemplo pode ser implementada contendo uma lista de produtos internamente (privada) e pode ser interessante que esse pedido ofereça um método público `getTotal()`, o que não quer dizer necessariamente que dentro exista um campo `total` privado, e sim que ele pode calcular esse total percorrendo a lista de produtos e somando os preços de um a um.

Um setter pode até alterar diretamente um campo privado, mas também pode (e deve) fazer a validação do novo valor que está sendo fornecido, pois ele age como um porteiro entre o lado externo e o interno, que fica protegido, inclusive de receber dados inválidos (o que deixaria o objeto num estado inválido).

Um objeto da classe `Pessoa` pode expor sua idade por um `getIdade()` calculada a partir de um campo `data_de_nascimento`. Igualmente, pode por alguma razão não ser interessante expor a data de nascimento diretamente, então evita-se criar um `getDataDeNascimento()`, por exemplo. Muito menos faria sentido haver um setter para modificar a data de nascimento, que por definição deveria ser fixa e imutável.

O mesmo princípio geral se aplica a construtores, que devem validar todos os argumentos passados a eles a fim de inicializar o estado interno do objeto de maneira válida.

Não sei se respondi sua pergunta porque não sei a sintaxe especifica do Kotlin para isso tudo, mas espero ter ajudado com esses importantes conceitos e dado uma base para encontrar a resposta na sintaxe.